# boolean variable javascript

Tags: javascript, boolean, var

hi need help in how to work the " var disruptive variable. I need to take a answer in
 "Y or N". and put in the 3rd condition in the if

```
     <script type="text/javascript">

     var examResult;
     var attendance;
     var disruptive;

     examResult=parseInt(prompt("Enter Exam result:",""));
     attendance=parseInt(prompt("Enter Attendance:",""));
     disruptive=prompt("Disruptive Y/N:",""); 
     if((examResult>=40) && (attendance>=75) &&("disruptive))
     {
 document.write("You have passed");
     }
     else
     {
document.write("You have failed")
     }

     </script>
```

Comment: `if((examResult>=40) && (attendance>=75) && (disruptive !== "Y")) {...}`?

Comment: in your if statement there is typo: a double quotation mark `"disruptive` remove it so it becomes `disruptive`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 var examResult;
 var attendance;
 var disruptive;

 examResult=parseInt(prompt("Enter Exam result:",""));
 attendance=parseInt(prompt("Enter Attendance:",""));
 disruptive=prompt("Disruptive Y/N:",""); 
 if((examResult>=40) && (attendance>=75) &&(disruptive=="Y"))
 {
    concole.log("You have passed");
 }
 else
 {
    concole.log("You have failed")
 }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FAnt7/)

Comment: Instead of `document.write()`, try `document.body.innerHTML = "You have passed"` - it's less destructive.

Comment: @Pavlo: Please check my Demo, I am using `console.log`

Comment: Better, but console messages isn't something that regular user will see.

Comment: @Pavlo It is just example, User can customize according him

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement is having error. Remove '"' (double quotes) and then try

Answer (score 0):

Add this before your if statement

```
 disruptiveString=prompt("Disruptive Y/N:","");
 if (disruptiveString == "Y"){
        disruptive = true;
    }
else{
    disruptive = false;
}
```

Also as noted by @Java Buddy, remove the " in your statement

Comment: No need to additional condition